# I'm getting Invalid maximum heap size when I set Xmx and agentlib

Tags: java, c

Here are the arguments that I am using:

> -Xmx1024m -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=11999

The -Xmx1024m work fine without passing the -agentlib, and the -agentlib works fine without Xmx. Can you set the max heap size while using the agentlib?

My jar file is getting launched via C code:

```
execlp(myJavaPath, myJavaPath, myDebugOptions,"-DFBLog4j=true","-jar","myJar.jar", NULL);
```

Where myDebugOptions contain the char* "-Xmx1024m -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=11999". When I try to run this same command via commandline (in Solaris 10, JVM 1.6.0_17) it works fine.

Comment: do you mean,JVM didn't launched when you used both of these options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass each command line argument as different parameters to execlp.

The commandline you're executing would be the same as running this from a command line:

```
java '-Xmx1024m -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=11999' -DFBLog4j=true -jar myJar.jar
```

Which won't work either, essentially -Xmx and -agentlib gets passed as a single argument.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this doesn't work is because -Xmx1024 and -agentlib: are two different arguments. When calling execlp they need to be passed in as two different arguments. When I called execlp like:

```
execlp(myJavaPath, myJavaPath, myDebugOptions, "-Xmx1024m", "-DFBLog4j=true", "-jar", "/usr/mprint/bin/QDirectJServer.jar", NULL);
```

it worked as expected with no errors. Even those myDebugOptions contained a space it was still considering it as one argument.

Answer (score 1):

If your defined memory capacity is greater than your system physical memory then this kind of error will generate.

update defined memory according t the physical memory.

```
For Example if your physical memory of Ram is 2GB(2048m) and yo defined the JVM as 
-Xmx4096m then this error will come.
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried this one and it worked :

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>java -Xmx1024m -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=11999 -version
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 11999
   java version "1.6.0_17"
   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_17-b04)
   Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 14.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Same here (using 1.6.0_20 on Mac OS).